# Ruby can't even require standard libraries from within vim

Tags: ruby, vim, require

In `irb` and when using `ruby` everything works. `require 'pathname' ==> True`.

In a vimscript file this fails however

```
ruby << EOF
print 5
require 'pathname'
print 6
```

fails however with `LoadError: (eval):20:in 'require': no such file to load -- pathname`. The `5` is printed though.

My operating system is `cat /etc/redhat-release ==> CentOS release 5.2 (Final)`. I'm trying to get LustyExplorer to work.

Lastly, vim seems to be installed with ruby.

```
$ vim --version | grep +ruby
+printer +profile +python +quickfix +reltime +rightleft +ruby +scrollbind
```

---

This has nothing to do with rubygems I believe since not even standard libraries are accessible.

Comment: I gave up on this. I ended up using CtrlP extension rather than Lusty.

Answer (score 1):

I don't experience the same problem, I did, however, compile vim with static ruby; I don't know if that setup would help you.

```
$ vim --version | grep +ruby
-python3 +quickfix +reltime +rightleft +ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent 
Linking: gcc   -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE  -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim    -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE -lm -lnsl  -lselinux  -lncurses -lacl -lattr -lgpm  -L/usr/lib -llua  -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DynaLoader/DynaLoader.a -L/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE -lperl -lresolv -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc -L/usr/local/lib/python2.6/config -lpython2.6 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic  -L/usr/lib64 -ltcl8.4 -ldl -lpthread -lieee -lm -lruby-static -ldl -lcrypt -lm  -L/opt/local/ruby-1.8.7/lib
```